# ¿Cómo recojo los datos desde un asp:DropDownList para un SQLCommand?

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Tengo este código en asp:net:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvDetalle" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id_Averia" DataSourceID="sdsDetalle" DefaultMode="Edit">
<td>Verificar servicios existentes</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="VerificarServicios" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>N/A</asp:ListItem>                                           
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Si</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</asp:FormView>
```

Y necesito recoger el valor seleccionado para poder almacenarlo en una base de datos:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDetalle" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Id_Averia, VerificarServicios FROM [Detalle] WHERE ([Id_Averia] = @Id_Averia)" UpdateCommand="SP_GuardarDetalle" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="-1" Name="Id_Averia" QueryStringField="Id_Averia" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="VerificarServicios" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Necesito saber qué me falta para que funcione, ya que el código, además, tiene otros elementos diferentes a `asp:DropDownList` que tienen la misma configuración y si entran en la base de datos.

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Necesitas obtener el valor seleccionado del `DropDownList` VerificarServicios?

Comment: Si, necesito saber cómo recoger el valor para darlo de parámetro para realizar el update.

Comment: @OniNeit, ¿Tu `FormView` estará enlazada al `SqlDataSource`? ¿Cuando se selecciona un nuevo valor automaticamente se debe guardar en la BD?

Comment: @Davlio está enlazado, si no, el resto de elementos no devolverían datos a  la BD

Comment: @OniNeit la respuesta que indico solo está relacionado a relacionar el control `DropDownList` con el `FormView`, pero si quieres más pautas de como funciona podrías ver [Modificar datos mediante un control FormView de servidor Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms227970(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la propiedad `DropDownList.SelectedValue` del que te da el valor seleccionado de la lista:

```
String servicioSeleccionado = VerificarServicios.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías considerar enlazar tu parámetro al control.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDetalle" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Id_Averia, VerificarServicios FROM [Detalle] WHERE ([Id_Averia] = @Id_Averia)" UpdateCommand="SP_GuardarDetalle" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="-1" Name="Id_Averia" QueryStringField="Id_Averia" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>    
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="VerificarServicios" ControlId="VerificarServicios" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Al momento de ejecutar el siguiente código en algún evento se enlazará al control.

```
sdsDetalle.Update();
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Propiedad SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Está enlazado, se me olvidó ponerlo a la hora de transcribir la parte del formview